# How to add a command for copying a selected file's path to the clipboard to File Explorer's context menu

Tags: powershell, contextmenu, exe, explorer, regedit

Ok so basically, what I want to do, is copy the file path of a file by using the right click selection for said file. I found a way to add an [option to the right click selection,](https://www.wikihow.com/Add-New-Options-to-Right-Click-Menu-in-Windows) but I need an exe file to add the function. I have an application that will convert .ps1 files to .exe files, but I don't know where to start with the program, or how to get it to get the path of the file I right click on. Any one have an idea?

Comment: In Windows 7+, you can hold down the Shift key _before_ right-clicking, which will make a `Copy as path` command appear in the context menu, which copies the selected item's full path to the clipboard. Do you need support for earlier OS versions?

Comment: in windows 7 you can <shift><rt-clk> on a file, then select `copy as path` to get the full path of a file into the clipboard. if that aint what you are seeking, then please try to explain your needs in a different way ... [*grin*]

Comment: Ok thank you, I am in windows 10, but it still works. Heck, I didn't even know that holding *shift* did anything to the right click function. Thanks for the help!